# Only Wordpress logo loads

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Good Day,

So I am in the process of setting up a wordpress website and have put on a theme.

Since beginning to customize it, I've realized that the page stopped loading all its contents, and just began loading the logo against a blank page. [image: How it should look]

[image: how it looks]

The blue rectangle is where the logo will be going. 
The theme is JobCareer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you opened developer tools to see why the files aren't loading? Maybe your server is missing a folder or something

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have done the checks indeed. The only error that comes up is one stating that the maps API is not present. This error was also present when it was working, so I doubt that is a major cause for concern. As far as I can tell, there are no missing folders or files either.

Comment: Maybe set WP_Debug in you config file to true